Find radius of convergence for two series product
I have a equation like this:
(u + v + w + 2 u w + 2 v w + 2u v + 3u v w)/[1 - (v w +  uv + uw + 2 u v w)]
 u := Sum[ Exp[n k^2 - A k^2 HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n, 
  1, \[Infinity]}]
 w := Sum[ Exp[n k^2 + B k HarmonicNumber[n]] ((1 - r)/(2 z))^n , {n, 
  1, \[Infinity]}]
 v := r/(z-r)

The coefficients A,B and r are numerical values in this problem and z changes over k. I replaced these three functions in my equation.
The convergence of this equation is important for me. I set the denominator's output equal to zero to find the roots that cause divergence.By changing the value of k, z changes. Ultimately, I want to plot Log[z] for different values of k.
I know the radius of convergence for u and w. The radius for u and w are z = (1-r)e^(k^2) But how about u*v? What is the radius convergence for the product?

You question is unclearly formulated. SumConvergence[  Exp[n  k^2 - A  k^2  HarmonicNumber[n]]  ((1 - r)/(2  z))^n, n] results in E^Re[k^2] Abs[(-1 + r)/z] < 2. The same for another series.

@user64494 the result is Abs[(1-r)/2]e^k^2. I know both of them are the same z. But I don't know about the product of the two series.

Look in Encyclopedia of Mathematics and you'll know that the radius of the convergence of the product is the same.

thanks for your help.

For any complex analytic function the radius of convergency of its series expansion around a point $z_0$ is the distance to the nearest singularity.
So by complex analytical combinations of two or more functions the series of the combination around a point converges inside the circle of radius of the distance to any singularity of finite sums and products.
Rational functions develop additonal poles at the zeros of the denominator, so their distances form the point of expansion add to the set of singular points.
For rational functions of functions, different Laurent series are an option, converging in an annulus bounded by two poles on the inner and outer circle.

Thanks for your answer. Is it possible for you to provide more details about paragraph 2?
